# iCloud base URL null

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, url, icloud

I have the following piece of code and am trying to access iCloud directory.

```
(void) reloadFiles{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 

    NSString *containerID=@"KSC75JA957.Dcdmc.TinyPix";

    NSURL *cloudURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

    NSLog(@"got cloudURL %@", cloudURL); 

    self.query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];

    query.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like '*.tinypix'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];

    query.searchScopes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope];

    [query startQuery];                       
}
```

However, when i run my application I am unable to get the cloud url. And am getting the following errors.

```
 got cloudURL (null)

 item update error: 0, Error

 Domain=LibrarianErrorDomain Code=10 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. 

(LibrarianErrorDomain error 10 - Unable to configure the collection.)"

 UserInfo=0xce65470 {NSDescription=Unable to configure the collection.}
```

Comment: Are you going to use cloudURL? If that's the case, maybe the NIL-identifier has something to do with it?

Comment: I had tried using the container identifier instead of 'nil' but I still got the same error. So i guess, that's not the issue.

Comment: when the `cloudURL` is `nil` means the iCould service is not available on that device.

Answer (score 1):

"Unable to configure the collection" means that Documents syncing is somehow disabled.

Are you signed into iCloud and do you have Documents & Data enabled?
`cloudURL` will be `nil` if Documents syncing is not enabled for one of these two reasons.

If `cloudURL` is `nil`, you should not attempt to use iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

You sure that you enabled icloud on the device? Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515986/icloud-error-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-librarianerrordoman-error-10):

```
this is the error that occurs when you haven't enabled iCloud on the device on which you are testing. once i enabled iCloud on the device, the error stopped occurring in my log.

and so now i know what error to check for in order to present the user with a dialog saying "connecting to iCloud won't work until you sign up for iCloud in the system preferences".
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the iCloud support for your App on the developer portal web site first off all.